# Counting lines words characters and filenotfound exception java eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception, counting

// The problem is it keeps saying 0 for lines and words.  It's counting characters properly though.  And I'm not really sure how to add a FileNotFoundException really.  My teacher didn't teach our class this even.  Everyone in my class is struggling :(

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

public class FileReader
{  
public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException        
{ 
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);           

        System.out.println("File to be read: ");
        String inputFile = console.next();

        File file = new File(inputFile);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

        int words = 0;
        int lines = 0;
        int chars = 0;

        in = new Scanner(file);
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            in.next();
            chars++;
        }
        in = new Scanner(file);
        while(in.hasNextLine())
        {
            in.nextLine();
            lines++;
        }
        in = new Scanner(file);
        while(in.hasNextByte())
        {
            in.nextByte();
            words++;
        }

        System.out.println("Number of lines: " + lines);
        System.out.println("Number of characters: " + chars);
        System.out.println("Number of words: " + words);
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by add filenotfoundexception ? add in try-catch clause ?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant sorry

Comment: We won't do your homework !

Comment: Hint: suppose in the console input you deliberately enter the name of file which does not exist on the system.  At which line(s) will this become a problem?  There's your try-catch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of throwing the exception always try to catch the exception. Put your entire main code in try block and catch all the exceptions in a catch block. Exception handling is easy in java. A small tutorial on try catch can help you more.

You are getting that FileNotFoundException because you are not specifying the complete path of the file. `File f = new File(complete/path/of/file);`

console.next() will only give you the text you enter into console but not the entire path.

I would suggest you to make a string with the complete path and give it to File().

I think this explanation is too much for your homework ;)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the first while loop you are actually counting number of words but assigning it to chars. Number of characters can be easily counted from length of each words in this loop itself.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("File to be read: ");
        String inputFile = console.next();

        File file = new File(inputFile);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

        int words = 0;
        int lines = 0;
        int chars = 0;

        in = new Scanner(file);
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            chars += in.next().length();
            words++;
        }
        in = new Scanner(file);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            in.nextLine();
            lines++;
        }

        /*
         * in = new Scanner(file); while(in.hasNextByte()) { in.nextByte();
         * words++; }
         */

        System.out.println("Number of lines: " + lines);
        System.out.println("Number of characters: " + chars);
        System.out.println("Number of words: " + words);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code right now, and when I entered an empty file, it read 5 lines, 135 characters, ad 5 words.  I can't find out why though.

Comment: I tested with an empty file and output is OK.